# I cannot use plugin josegonzales/cakephp/upload for cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, plugins, upload

after following all steps to install upload plugin of josegonzales http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
when try to access a view the server give me this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\webroot\index.php on line 33
```

any help is apprechated

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your app to use 
[Middleware](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html/)